# How can I convert a sting arrray to float and sum the valus inside it? Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I have string array with numeric vaues and i wont to convert them to float. My problem is that i can convert them and print thhem out but I cant sum them. Can anyone tell me how to fix that problem,

```
    for(int j=0; j<=val.length-1;j++){
            float valf = Float.parseFloat(val[j]);
            if(valf!=0){
                System.out.println(valf);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You definitely can sum them out, you're simply not doing it in your loop. Try to declare a `float sum = 0` out of the loop and then `float += valf` inside the loop, and at the end of the loop the `sum` will contain what you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a sum variable before entering the for loop.
For example:

```
float sum = 0;
for(int j=0; j<=val.length-1;j++){
    float valf = Float.parseFloat(val[j]);
    if(valf!=0){
        System.out.println(valf);
        sum += valf; 
    }
}
System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
```